# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. None of the answers in other posts resolved the issue

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am doing everything according to the guide but it's not working.

It is giving me this error.

> Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

Also this error when I took off the [(ngModel)] of the items.

```
[ERROR ->]<ion-input type="text" formControlName="nome" name="nome" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
 "): ng:///HomePageModule/HomePage.html@59:10
No provider for NgControl ("
        <ion-item>
```

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule 
  ],

 import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

 inscricaoForm;

  constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder, inscricaoForm: FormGroup) {
    this.inscricaoForm = formBuilder.group({
      dataInscricao: ['', Validators.required],
      nome: ['', Validators.required],
      endereco: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

<form [formGroup]="inscricaoForm">
```

Comment: Why are you importing `FormModule and ReactiveFormsModule` twice ?

Comment: Also with [(ngModel)] this error appears:
 ng:///HomePageModule/HomePage.html@29:8
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-datetime'.
1. If 'ion-datetime' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.

Comment: because one is in the app.component.ts and the other is on my component

Comment: And here is my packages.json}
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",

Answer (score 0):

No need twice import of `FormModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`.

And no need to inject your own property. Try like this :

```js
app-module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```js
app-component.ts

import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

...

inscricaoForm : FormGroup;

constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.inscricaoForm = formBuilder.group({
    dataInscricao: ['', Validators.required],
    nome: ['', Validators.required],
    endereco: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}
```

Please find a [working stackblits](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jojb7a)

Comment: @tiedmud I update my post adding a Stackblitz, please check.

Comment: I did the same, and it didn't work, and also I modified the code and I put [(ngModel)] and it isn't working too, I think the problem is the FormsModule not working correctly. Do you know how I can make it work correctly?

Error in the ngModel:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'.

Comment: If you have the same code as me, it should work. The problem come from somewhere else :/

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I had to put ReactiveModulesImport in my home.module.ts file! It was so simple got me so troubled!